# How does lifetime immunity work?

Tags: immune-system

Why do we get a lifetime immunity against particular diseases like `smallpox` ?

Why don't we get immunity against all diseases we have already been through ?

Comment: You don't get lifetime immunity with vaccination against smallpox

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?